# Is this proof of $|x| \leq \sum |x_i|$ correct, incorrect, or flawed?

Tags: inequality, vectors, inner-products

This is problem 1-1 from Spivak Calculus on Manifolds

My proof of $|x| \leq \sum |x_i|$ is slightly different from others I've seen. I would like to know if the proof is correct, but also -if it is correct- if it is not quite as good as the standard one. (less rigoruous?) (This is the usual proof: problem 1-1 http://vision.caltech.edu/~kchalupk/spivak.html

> $|x| \equiv \sqrt{{\sum(x_i)^2}}$
>
> For clarity, take $i=2$.
>
> $|x||x|=|x_1|^2+|x_2|^2$
>
> $|x|=|x_1|\frac{|x_1|}{|x|}+|x_2|\frac{|x_2|}{|x|}$
>
> $\frac{|x_i|}{|x|} \leq 1$
>
> $|x| \leq |x_1|+|x_2|$
>
> For the general case take $i=n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is basically correct. Of course you have to assume $x\ne0$ (but in this case the inequality trivially holds).

First you note that, for $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)\ne0$,
$$
|x_i|\le|x|=\sqrt{|x_1|^2+\dots+|x_n|^2}
$$
just by squaring. Then you have
$$
0\le \frac{|x_i|}{|x|}\le 1
$$
so
$$
|x|=\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|\frac{|x_i|}{|x|}\le\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|
$$

Comment: That seems to be basically what I've done. I suppose I'm really asking a question about mathematical presentation. I just feel that I'm always proving things out of order somehow. My solutions are always a little backwards or mixed up.

Comment: @MadScientist Yes, that was just a question of putting things in better order.